# Assigning an ObservableCollection of an object to a field that is an ObservableCollection of an interface

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, interface, uwp

I'm currently trying to assign an `ObservableCollection` of an object (in the example below: `ObservableCollection<A>`), to a field in a parent class that is an `ObservableCollection` of an interface implemented by the object (in the example below: `public ObservableCollection<IOrderable> childModels`, where type `A` implements `IOrderable`).


This can be seen in the following:

```
public class A : IOrderable { }

public class B : IOrderable { }

public class Term
{
  public ObservableCollection<A> aCollection { get; set; }
}

public class Year
{
  public ObservableCollection<B> bCollection { get; set; }
}

public abstract class InfoListViewModelBase : ViewModelBase
{
  public ObservableCollection<IOrderable> childModels { get; set; }    
}

public class TermViewModel : InfoListViewModelBase
{
  public TermViewModel(Term t) 
  {
    this.childModels = t.aCollection;
  }
}

public class YearViewModel : InfoListViewModelBase
{
  public TermViewModel(Year y) 
  {
    this.childModels = y.bCollection;
  }
}
```

The issue is that `this.childModels = t.aCollection;` and `this.childModels = y.bCollection;` both do not work, instead giving the error "Cannot implicitly convert type `ObservableCollection<A>` to `ObservableCollection<IOrderable>`" and "Cannot implicitly convert type `ObservableCollection<B>` to `ObservableCollection<IOrderable>`"

Is there a correct way of achieving this desired result between the classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make your `InfoListViewModelBase` generic.

```
public abstract class InfoListViewModelBase<T> : ViewModelBase where T:IOrderable
{
    public ObservableCollection<T> childModels { get; set; }    
}
```

Your implementations become

```
public class TermViewModel : InfoListViewModelBase<A> { }

public class YearViewModel : InfoListViewModelBase<B> { }
```